# Isn't there any way to uninstall fonts using inno setup script?

Tags: fonts, inno-setup

I wondered if I could get some useful advice from you.

**I am trying to replace fonts while installation of a package using inno setup.**

These two fonts are installed on Windows OS machines using a .TTC(True Type Collection) file. Thing is, the TTC file itself should not exist after the installation.

I tried the following codes:

---

**[InstallDelete]**

**Type:** files; **Name:** "{fonts}\CUSTOMIZED_FONTS.TTC"

**[Files]**

**Source:** "CUSTOMIZED1.TTF";  **DestDir:** "{fonts}";  **FontInstall:** "CORRECT_FONT_NAME_1";  **Flags:** ignoreversion

**Source:** "CUSTOMIZED2.TTF";  **DestDir:** "{fonts}";  **FontInstall:** "CORRECT_FONT_NAME_2";  **Flags:** ignoreversion

---

Thought these codes would delete previously installed TTC fonts and install new fonts without any TTC file generated.

But it turned out with TTC file gone, and two fonts not so properly installed so the OS could not recognize newly installed fonts after all.

On Windows 7 machine, the newly installed fonts could not be displayed in preview mode due to some corrupted font error messages.

On Windows 10 machine, the newly installed fonts did not show in the windows fonts folder.

Would there any way for me to resolve the situation?

**I want to replace two existing fonts installed using a ttc file with new two ttf filed fonts.**

Your kind advice would be a lot helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not do uninstall fonts. They may be needed on your customer system. read : https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/88 ! Inno Setup will not do it for you. You have to write an application that can do it for you.

Comment: Followed the link you provided and learned several important things matter to me. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)